# Generate viewmodels by LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have two lists

```
user.Roles
repository.Roles
```

and RoleViewModel

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public bool InRole { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public RoleViewModel() { }

    public RoleViewModel(Role role,bool inRole)
    {
        this.RoleID = role.RoleID;
        this.Name = role.Name;
        this.InRole = inRole;
    }
}
```

I need to generate any collection like `List<RoleViewModel>` which will be a composition of RoleViewModel items with inRole field set to true. And all other possible roles which are placed in repository.Roles collection and will be converted to RoleViewModels.

Can I use linq to generate needed list?

Thank you

Comment: It generates only list, containing user.Roles, but I need a list with all possible roles, but with selected inRole field for user.Roles.

Comment: the code you wrote won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a view model for every role in the repository, and if the user is in that role, the `inRole` argument to be true. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

To do that, you need a left join from the repository roles to the user's roles:

```
from role in repository.Roles
join userRole in user.Roles on role.RoleID equals userRole.RoleID into userRoles
from userRole in userRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new RoleViewModel(role, userRole != null)
```

This joins the set of roles in the repository to the set of roles for the user. It places the matching user roles into the `userRoles` sequence, then uses `DefaultIfEmpty` to return null for `userRole` if the user is not in the repository role. This way, if `userRole` is not null, the user is in the repository role, but if `userRole` is null,  the user is not in the repository role.

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I nedded.

Comment: Cool solution! I think you could also remove the third line (`from userRole in userRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()`) and then use in the last line instead: `select new RoleViewModel(role, userRoles.Any())`.

Comment: @Slauma: Interesting idea. I want to keep the answer in its original accepted form, but I like your approach too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you just need to fix your linq to call the constructor instead of assigning values to (non-existent) properties.

```
List<RoleViewModel> models = (from r1 in repository.Roles 
                              join r2 in user.Roles on r1.RoleID equals r2.RoleID 
                              select new RoleViewModel(r1, true)).ToList();
```

Comment: You spotted the misuse of his constructor first, so +1